# gcc10 wants an extra .so file that gcc8 does not need for linking

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker, shared-libraries

Im compiling my C++ code with an gcc10 and the linker wants an libspeckle.so file that i do not have.
However compiling the same programm with gcc8 or gcc9 and the same compiler and linker flags, it does not need the libspeckle.so file for linking and it works just fine.

For a beginner like me that is very confusing because i cant execute/link my programm with any modern compiler, i tried gcc10, gcc11, clang13, clang14, clang15, but nothing worked besides the gcc8 and gcc9 compiler.

For linkers i also tried out ld, gold, ldd and mold, no difference.

I tried using the -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs linker flag, but then i can't execute my programm.

Could someone help me understand this.

```json
"generator": "Ninja Multi-Config",
"environment": {
    "COMPILER": "gcc11",
    "cmakeBuildOptions": "-- -v",
    "CC": "gcc-11",
    "CXX": "g++-11",
    "ARCHITECTURE": "x64",
    "LDFLAGS": "-g",
    "CFLAGS": "-fsanitize=address -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -m64 -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fPIC",
    "CXXFLAGS": "-fsanitize=address -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -m64 -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fPIC"
}
```

ldd from executable compiled with gcc8 =>

```
ldd ./UnitTest | grep -i libspeckle
```

ldd from executable compiled with gcc11 =>

```
ldd ./UnitTest | grep -i libspeckle
        libspeckle.so.1 => not found
```

Comment: Without showing your build configuration it's impossible to tell anything I'm afraid.

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce on https://godbolt.org ?

Comment: the problem with this is that i have a lot of dependencies that are not officially found, and i also don't know which function is even used from the .so file. But if I build the whole thing for arm64 then it doesn't have the dependency either and the compiler doesn't matter.

Comment: Re. `"...i also don't know which function is even used from the .so"`: why not?  Please provide the actual error message(s) as text verbatim.

Comment: `Odonata_UnitTest: error while loading shared libraries: libspeckle.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: But those are errors shown when you run `ldd` on the already successfully compiled and linked `Odonata_UnitTest ` executable.  It sounds like it's simply a case of your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env variable not containing the correct paths when you attempt to run the app.

Comment: but the gcc8 compiled executable does not need libspeckle.so, so i dont have to append my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: Isn't building on different machines with different library set? What about to try to build on the same machine just with different compilers?

Comment: @yvs2014 i did, in a docker container, same behavior. gcc8 and gcc9 works, but other compilers do not

Comment: is UnitTest made on the same machine in the same environment, and ldd outputs are also from the same machine and the same env? It looks distinctly

Comment: at least in the first case some links are referring to /usr/local/lib, whereas in the second output the same links are referring to /mnt/d/Projekte/.../conan/bin/Release. Plus: even the same more std libs have different versions, what saying about different env or systems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `-fobjc-gc` flag in order to fix this. This should solve the problem.

You can check the flags [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html)